# Countdown in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, countdown, kivymd

I am creating an application which will display appointment times from a database.

I want to create a countdown timer which displays the amount of time left until the next appointment in hours, minutes and seconds. Any idea how to implement this with Kivy?

After some research, I managed to add a stopwatch on my interface which counts seconds, but I have no idea how to compare the current time to the appointment time, and then display the remaining time.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty

class Sections(BoxLayout):
    label_text = StringProperty()

    number = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sections, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .1)

        self.increment_time(0)

    
    def increment_time(self, interval):
        self.number -= .1

    def start(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .1)

   
    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time)


kv = Builder.load_file('main text')

class AlHuda(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv


    def on_start(self):
        pass



AlHuda().run()
```

```
<Sections>:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 800

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Timer'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:

            text: str(round(root.number))
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How about thinking countdown timer as reversed implementation of stopwatch that's bounded on both side ?

Comment: I added some of my code.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean by bounded on both sides